# not able to open System setting after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04.
After upgrade I am not able to open System Settings
I ran the below command on terminal

```
gnome-control-center
```

Below is the output for above command

> (unity-control-center:19276): Gdk-ERROR **: The program
>   'unity-control-center' received an X Window System error. This
>   probably reflects a bug in the program. The error was 'BadRequest
>   (invalid request code or no such operation)'.   (Details: serial 179
>   error_code 1 request_code 157 (GLX) minor_code 19)   (Note to
>   programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;    that
>   is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.    To debug
>   your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment    variable
>   to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful    backtrace
>   from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
>   Trace/breakpoint trap

Can anyone please help to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't see how this is dupe of that ?  Answer was, user knocked there PC over and broke there drive. @DavidCole How are they related  ?

Answer (score 0):

As seen at www.ubuntu.com, do these commands

```
`ubuntu-support-status

cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

sudo grep -R proxy /etc/apt/*

grep proxy  /etc/environment

echo $http_proxy

echo $ftp_proxy

grep proxy /etc/bash.bashrc

grep proxy ~/.bashrc

cat /etc/apt/apt.conf

sudo fuser -vvv /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo fuser -vvv /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

cat /etc/lsb-release

uname -a

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock 

sudo rm  /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status  ||  sudo cp /var/backups/apt.extended_states.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial

LANG=C;sudo apt-get clean

LANG=C;sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo dpkg --clear-avail

LANG=C;sudo apt-get -f install

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --fix-missing install

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --fix-missing update -o APT::Cache-Limit=100000000

LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=100000000 && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`
```

and send the output status to me via a comment. Then if that doesn't work, it may be very simple as to just do

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to fix installed Ubuntu programs.